# ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' with mlens

Tags: python, ensemble-learning

today i wanted to implement SuperLearner class with help of mlens, but when i run this code :

```
from mlens.ensemble import SuperLearner
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC,SVC
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import  GaussianNB,MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from collections.abc import Sequence
def get_acuracy(y,yhat):
    return accuracy_score(y,yhat)
def get_list_models():
    model =list()
    model.append(SVC())
    model.append(DecisionTreeClassifier())
    model.append(RandomForestClassifier())
    return model
def get_super_learner(X):
    super =SuperLearner(scorer=get_acuracy,folds=10)
    model =get_list_models()
    super.add(model)
    super.add_meta(LogisticRegression(max_iter=67000))
    return super

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=100)
super_learner =get_super_learner(X)
super_learner.fit(X,y)
print(super_learner.data)
```

i got following  errors :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

i know that  Sequence can be imported from collections.abc, but  how can i  update it for the mlens framework? it  mlens outdated?is there any alternative for this library?

Answer (score 0):

Go
*C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mlens\externals\sklearn\type_of_target.py:10*

You can see `from collections import Sequence` at line 10

Change it `from collections.abc import Sequence`

I got same Error in Python 3.10
Maybe `collections` package version issue..

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35805824)