# pyinstaller <ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'>

Tags: wxpython, pyinstaller

Environment

- Window10
- Spyder IDE 5.4.3
- Python 3.11.5 64-bit
- pyinstaller 5.6.2

When I ran the pyinstaller for my code, I got the traceback below.

I'd like to know why I bumped into this desperate problem and how to tackle it.

I've searched similar questions here([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434346/importerror-cannot-import-name-sequence-from-collections-with-mlens), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815939/pyinstaller-failed-to-import-module-pyinstaller-hooks-0-pydoc)) but not the same cases.

Any comments would be helpful for me =)

```
> pyinstaller main.spec
4087 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.6.2
4088 INFO: Python: 3.11.5 (conda)
4106 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
4112 INFO: UPX is not available.
4115 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\dazzling\\Documents\\wxPython\\Project001']
6382 INFO: checking Analysis
6483 INFO: Building because Analysis-00.toc is bad
6483 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
6490 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
6503 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'numpy'. Please take care they do not conflict.
6527 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
23658 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
23977 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'same folder(to save letters)'...
31812 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
35817 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
35986 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
36005 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\python.exe
36305 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\dazzling\Documents\wxPython\Project001\main.py
37125 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
4022 INFO: NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
43561 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
43765 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
45683 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
47035 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
48000 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
48739 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
50665 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
51602 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-psutil.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
52081 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
55567 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
56568 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
70135 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
70483 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
71593 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
72245 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-py.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
74482 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
75103 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
91269 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
92035 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'Same folder(to save letters)\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
92587 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
92664 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
93287 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
105608 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
106501 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi from 'Same folder(to save letters)\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-gi.py'.
106861 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
106970 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
111540 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
112467 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
113820 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
117010 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'Same folder(to save letters)\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
120169 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
122314 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
127401 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
131006 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-wcwidth.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
134146 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
137372 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-parso.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
139178 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-docutils.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
158796 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sphinx.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\application.py", line 27, in <module>
    from sphinx.environment import BuildEnvironment
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\environment\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.events import EventManager
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\events.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sphinx.util.inspect import safe_getattr
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\inspect.py", line 18, in <module>
    from sphinx.pycode.ast import ast  # for py36-37
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\pycode\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from zipfile import ZipFile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
170496 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
176026 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
181787 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
184320 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
187445 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'Same folder(to save letters)\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
189434 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
190786 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
206331 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bcrypt.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
206699 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
209768 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platformdirs.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
212947 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
220469 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nacl.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
220894 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
226320 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
227613 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-shelve.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
228653 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
229636 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
238524 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
244054 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
246442 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pyarrow.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
252274 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
253279 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numba.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
254597 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-llvmlite.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
266641 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
266935 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
266940 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
272414 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-dask.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
276312 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lz4.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
276978 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-h5py.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
279118 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bokeh.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
286785 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xyzservices.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
292186 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-botocore.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
300354 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
300679 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'Same folder(to save letters)'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
306795 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-argon2.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
308651 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-notebook.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
315631 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-anyio.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
339212 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-keyring.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
358028 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-openpyxl.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
359093 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
369250 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tables.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
370814 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
370962 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
371110 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
371267 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
371593 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
374661 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-wx.xrc.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
375328 INFO: Processing module hooks...
378101 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
378555 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.isoschematron.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
379387 WARNING: Hidden import "pyarrow.compat" not found!
380377 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zope.interface.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
385146 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
389411 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
389412 INFO: Matplotlib backend selection method: automatic discovery of used backends
389538 INFO: Selected matplotlib backends: ['WXAgg', 'WXAgg']
390435 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
395569 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
395766 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
396406 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
396408 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
396410 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
396453 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
404606 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 114, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
             ^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 179, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 60, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 963, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 885, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "main.spec", line 3, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
        ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 410, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 579, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 329, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 447, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module(keep_module_ref=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 387, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 609, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 605, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1120, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 945, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 721, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-sqlalchemy.py", line 31, in <module>
    dialects = eval(dialects.strip())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 0

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `conda remove pathlib` or `conda uninstall pathlib` whatever the conda command is to get rid of `pathlib`

Answer (score 1):

Try `conda remove pathlib` or `conda uninstall pathlib` or whatever the conda command is to get rid of pathlib.

pathlib is part of the python3 stdlib, but the one that is trying to import from is a 3rd party module that is likely really old.  You need to remove that library from your site packages so when it reads an import statement it first looks in the standard modules

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. 
It yielded another error but I think I can handle it soon.

Comment: I reinstalled all the programs, including Anaconda. And the problem has gone. =)